# Value returned of a form with Stripe CardElement is undefined React Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, stripe-payments, state

I'm new to this and try to create a dropdown list with my product names and use the key of this products (I have a Django Backend) to then proceed to payment with Stripe.

The problem is that the value of my product selected in my dropdown list (ie the variable named SelectedPlan) passed down here is 'undefined' ...but when I pass the value like a string 'string_value_of_my_Stripe_product' for example everything is fine and the payment and subscription work correctly.

The problem seems to be with the fact that the state is not updated correctly to the value in the form ie `e.target.value` does not update when I select the product in the userform

...this part :

```
 Axios
   .post("../myAPI/blablabla", {
    SelectedPlan: this.SelectedPlan,
 })
```

Here are the 2 files I have ... SubscribeForm.js and a Billing.js.

I'm sorry there's maybe too much code but it's maybe necessary to get thw whole idea...I try to not show the unnecessary...

Thanks in advance !!!

Here is my SubscribeForm.js

```
import React from "react";
import {
  CardElement,
  injectStripe,
  Elements,
  StripeProvider,
}

const subscriptionOptions = [
  {...values here},
];

class StripeForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: false,
    error: null,
    SelectedPlan: null,
  };

  onSelectedPlanChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      SelectedPlan: e.target.value,
    });
  };

  submit = (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ loading: true, error: null });
    if (this.props.stripe) {
      this.props.stripe.createToken().then((result) => {
        if (result.error) {
          this.setState({
            error: result.error.message,
            loading: false,
            SelectedPlan: null,
          });
        } else {
          Axios
            .post(".../myAPI/blablabla/", {
              SelectedPlan: this.SelectedPlan,
            })
            .then((res) => {
              this.setState({
                loading: false,
              });
              this.props.handleUserDetails();
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
              this.setState({
                loading: false,
                error: err.response.data.message,
              });
            });
        }
      });
    } else {
      console.log("Stripe js hasn't loaded yet");
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { loading, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Divider />
        {error && <Message error header="There was an error" content={error} />}

        <Form onSubmit={this.submit}>
          <Form.Select
            options={subscriptionOptions}
            placeholder="SelectedPlan"
            onChange={this.onSelectedPlanChange}
            name="SelectedPlan"
            value={this.SelectedPlan}
          />

          <CardElement />

          <Button
            loading={loading}
            disabled={loading}
            type='submit'
          >
            Confirm
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedStripeForm = injectStripe(StripeForm);

class SubscribeForm extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <StripeProvider apiKey="my_test_key">
        <div>
          <Elements>
            <WrappedStripeForm {...this.props} />
          </Elements>
        </div>
      </StripeProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default SubscribeForm;
```

Here is my Billing.js :

```
import React from "react";
import SubscribeForm from "./SubscribeForm";

class Billing extends React.Component {
  state = {
...
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.handleUserDetails();
  }

...some code

handleUserDetails = () => {
    this.setState({
      loading: true,
    });
    Axios
      .get(".../myAPI/mybilling/")
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          billingDetails: res.data,
        });
        console.log("billing details ici");
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          error: err.response.data.message,
        });
      });
  };

  renderBillingDetails(details) {

    return (
      <Segment>
       ...some code
            <SubscribeForm handleUserDetails={this.handleUserDetails} />
       ...some code
      </Segment>
    );
  }
...some other code
}

export default Billing;
```

Comment: What do you get if you log `e.target.value` in `SubscribeForm.js`?

Comment: I get undefined also. Thanks for helping me !